# Add requested argument as a variable in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I'm trying to run a bash script and one of the tasks is to set up an SSH configuration, however when trying to add the key-agents, it requires that the passphrase be added (this is done once). For which I wanted to know if I could add the variable in the bash script and this would automatically add the requested passphrase.

In the current snippet of the bash script the last line ssh-add will run this as an alias within the *sourceme* file

> 'ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa'

### Bash Script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Running SSH Key Agent Setup"

echo "Change to SSH directory"
cd ~/.ssh/

echo "Run Sourceme File"
source ./sourceme

echo "Run Alias"
alias

echo "Set up SSH Agent"
sagent

echo "Add SSH Keys"
ssh-add

PASSPHRASE="RANDOM_PASSPHRASE"
```

### Argument Request

```
Enter passphrase for /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa: (HERE ENTER PASSPHRASE AUTOMATICALLY)
```

Comment: If you are going to hardcode the passphrase, you may as well just remove the passphrase from the key.

Comment: No, I will have as a wildcard, so each user can enter their own passphrase, my example might be bad

Comment: Then there's no reason for your script to get involved with the passphrase; let the user enter it when `ssh-add` requests it.

Comment: This runs as part of a pipeline, so the user will not be able to be prompted. Each user will have to create their own input file from the start...

Comment: Either the user types the passphrase when `ssh-add` asks for it, or you store it insecurely and subvert the reason for having a passphrase in the first place. There *may* be a third option (the macOS build of `ssh-add`, for example, has options for storing and retrieving passphrases in the user's keychain), but it's not clear what options exist for Linux.

Comment: good to know, makes sense, I'll take into consideration the approach...

Comment: You should add all details to your question about *how exactly* you (intend to) run this as part of a pipeline.

Comment: You want [`sshpass`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/sshpass.1.html)